# Put brackets around variables that end with sd

Tags: r

I have a large table and I would like to put brackets around every variable that ends with "_sd".

Here is an example:

```
a<- c(0,2,3,4,10,7,6,5,4,3)
b_sd<-c(0,2,3,4,8,6,5,4,3,1)
c<- c(0,2,3,4,10,7,6,5,4,3)
d_sd<-c(0,2,3,4,8,6,5,4,3,1)

dta <- data.frame(a=a, b_sd=b_sd, c=c, d_sd=d_sd)

dta

# this is the slow way:
dta[,2] <- paste0("(", dta[,2], ")")
dta[,4] <- paste0("(", dta[,4], ")")


# this is what I want:
dta
```

The above code will work, but it's very slow for all the variables that I have. How can I automate it? 1. find the variables that end with _sd and put brackets around them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
namesWithSd <- grep("_sd",names(dta))

dta[namesWithSd] <- lapply(dta[namesWithSd], function(colVals) {
  paste0("(",colVals,")")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is large, try the data.table package for operations like these. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) is a vignette if you want to know more.

Here is the code utilizing the data.table package :

```
library(data.table)
##Set as data table
setDT(dta)

##Select the relevant variables
sd_names<-grep("_sd",names(dta),value = T)

dta[,(sd_names):=lapply(.SD,function(x) {paste0("(",x,")")}),.SDcols=sd_names]

###
dta
```